# how to create term inside existing termset

Tags: development, powershell, term-set, term

how could i create terms inside existing group/termset

```
$TaxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site $TaxonomySite
$termStore=$TaxonomySession.TermStores["Managed MetaDataService"]
$group=$termStore.Groups["Users"]
$termSet=$group.TermSets["Name"]

foreach($termSet in $Content.Settings.Terms.Term)
{
    CreateTerm($termSet)        
}

$termStore.CommitAll()
```

---

I get this error

> Cannot index into a null Array
>   groups["Users"]
>   termsets["Department]
>   CreateTerm: The term CreateTerm is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

You can create term to a particular term set using

```
$termGroup = $termStore.Groups["GroupName"] 
$termSet = $termGroup.TermSets["TermSetName"]

$term = $termSet.CreateTerm("new term name") 
$termStore.CommitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
#Connect to Central Admin 
$taxonomySite = get-SPSite http://centraladminsite:port

#Connect to Term Store in the Managed Metadata Service Application 
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site $taxonomySite 
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"] 
write-host "Connection made with term store -"$termStore.Name

#Connect to the Group and Term Set 
$termStoreGroup = $termStore.Groups["Group Name"] 
$termSet = $termStoreGroup.TermSets["Term Set Name"]

#Create term, term description, and a synonym 
$term = $termSet.CreateTerm("Test Term", 1033) 
$term.SetDescription("This is a test", 1033) 
$term.CreateLabel("This is a test synonym", 1033, $false)

#Update the Term Store 
$termStore.CommitAll()
```

Source: 
[Create a new term in Existing Group and Term Set Under Managed Metadata Service Application with PowerShell](http://deepaksemwalsp.blogspot.com/2011/09/create-new-term-in-existing-group-and.html)

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression on "Test Term" and "This is test" and "This is a test synonym"

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below PowerShell function using Client Object to create a new term in a Term Set. This can can be executed from remote machine you need not to be on server.

You need to set few parameters and pass it to function.

Parameter explanation:

**$MMSbaseurl** - Its the URL to website on which you have termsets and groups for e.g. http://yoursite

**$credentials** - Your credentials to the site, you need to have enough permissions to access and edit meta data

**$GroupName** - Name of the group in Term Set lives

**$TermSetName** - Name of the term set in which you want to create a new term

**$lcid** - locale ID you are using

```
    function Create-NewTerm() {
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$MMSbaseurl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$GroupName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$TermSetName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][int]$lcid
    )

begin{

    Write-Host "Preparing for term store...." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    try{
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($MMSbaseurl)
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error:-->> Unable to create ClientContext at " $MMSbaseurl -ForegroundColor Red
    }

try
    {
        Write-Host "Binding to Term store through managed metadata services for ($MMSbaseurl) " -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $Context.Credentials = $credentials
        $MMS = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession]::GetTaxonomySession($Context)
        $Context.Load($MMS)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        Write-Host "Retrieving Term Stores" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $TermStores = $MMS.TermStores
        $Context.Load($TermStores)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()


        Write-Host "Binding term store" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $TermStore = $TermStores[0]
        $Context.Load($TermStore)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()


        Write-Host "Binding term store Groups" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $Groups = $TermStore.Groups
        $Context.Load($Groups)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        foreach($Group in $Groups) {
            if ((($Group.Name.ToLower()) -eq $GroupName.ToLower()))
            {   
                $SelectedGroup = $Group
                Write-Host "Group found." -ForegroundColor Cyan
                break
            }
        }

        $Context.Load($SelectedGroup)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()


        Write-Host "Bind to term set" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $TermSets = $SelectedGroup.TermSets
        $Context.Load($TermSets)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        foreach($TermSet in $TermSets) {
            if ((($TermSet.Name.ToLower()) -eq $TermSetName.ToLower()))
            {   
                $SelectedTermSet = $TermSet
                Write-Host "Term set found." -ForegroundColor Cyan
                break
            }
        }

        $Context.Load($TermSet)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()

        #Term creation
        #
        $NewTerm = $TermSet.CreateTerm("New Term", $lcid, [System.Guid]::NewGuid().toString())
        $Context.Load($NewTerm)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host "New term created successfully" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    }
    catch{
        Write-Host "Error -->>>> " $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
end{
    $Context.Dispose()
}   

}

#Get and Set credentials
$credentials = Get-Credential

#Call Function
#
Create-NewTerm "http:YourSite.com" $credentials "New Group" "New Term Set" 1033
```

Same function you can refer at this [blog](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/create-groups-term-sets-and-terms-in-a-term-store-using-csom-powershell-in-sharepoint-2013/)